# How to create table in SQL Server through ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a table in my database through ASP.NET Web API `HttpPost` method by sending datatypes and names of its columns.

There is nowhere I found that, everywhere people creating only rows of already created table. Please help!

Comment: Create dynamic query, fill with the params you pass, and execute it.

Comment: To create a table in a database, you execute a `CREATE TABLE` command. It's up to you how your solution does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to use SqlConnect and pure SQL sentence to achieve.You can try the following code.

```
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void test1(string tableName,string column1,string type1,string column2,string type2)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=192.168.2.68;Database=TestDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxx;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string sql =
                      $@"CREATE TABLE [{tableName}] (
                               -- Fields
                               {column1}  {type1},
                               {column2}  {type2},

                             )";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Test
[image]
Result
[image]
You can also try the following which add primary key column. And use Dictionary as input type.

```
        [HttpPost("test2")]
        public void test2(string tableName, Dictionary<string,string> columns)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=192.168.2.68;Database=TestDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=Q!q11111;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string sql =
                      $@"CREATE TABLE [{tableName}] (
                                --Fields
                               Id      int     IDENTITY(1,1),";      //create an AutoIncrement Id column;


                foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    sql=sql+(" "+column.Key + " " + column.Value + ", ");
                }
                sql = sql + $@"
                                --Constraints 
                                CONSTRAINT[CONSTRAINTPK_{tableName}] PRIMARY KEY(Id)  )"; //set Id as primary key

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }
```